# Float value with 2 decimal places

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In Android, the value entered into the EditText is converted to float using the following line of code.

```
        Float addPurchUnitCostPrice = Float.valueOf(addPurchaseCostPrice.getText().toString());
```

I would like to have the value of `addPurchUnitCostPrice` with 2 decimal places (always). How can this be done?

Comment: Float does not work that way. You can format it, but you can't restrict (or modify) the precision of the datatype.

Comment: try using BigDecimal

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point values don't have decimal places. They have binary places, and the two are incommensurable. If you want decimal places you have to use a decimal radix, i.e. `BigDecimal.`

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off using the [currency formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()) in Android, however it requires a double. The currency formatter will also deal with countries that use commas in place of decimal points.

So change your code to

```
double addPurchUnitCostPrice = Double.parseDouble(addPurchaseCostPrice.getText().toString());
NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String formattedPrice = currencyFormat.format(price);
```

You will create price with 2 decimal places and format according to the country defined by the users device.

Comment: I changed the format from float to double and used `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");`. Working as expected. The decimal values are getting limited to 2 decimal places. Also, the integer values are replaced with two zeros in the place of decimal. However, exploring the **currency formatter** and **Big Decimal**. Thanks everyone for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can just use BigDecimal for that